How to safely disable Docker’s iptables modifications for a custom firewall setup?
I am running a VPS with a Docker container hidden behind Nginx, which acts as a reverse proxy to route traffic. Docker modifies iptables rules dynamically using its custom chains by default, but I want full control over my firewall and do not want Docker to make these modifications.
To achieve this, I have set up custom iptables rules, as shown below. I would like to confirm if my approach is safe and whether there are any potential issues I should be aware of.
Here are the iptables rules from my current setup:
iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  500  172K MASQUERADE  0    --  *      enp1s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  0    --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0   

iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 180 packets, 8766 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  210 74025 ACCEPT     0    --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0 
  124  6032 ACCEPT     1    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
 4316 5095K ACCEPT     0    --  enp1s0 *       <my IP>              0.0.0.0/0           
  168 69867 ACCEPT     0    --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   35  4417 ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 475K packets, 157M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  819  114K ACCEPT     0    --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  769  704K ACCEPT     0    --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

I understand that Docker's default rules are more complex, but I don't fully grasp why. Is my simplified setup secure enough for production use, or am I missing some critical functionality provided by Docker’s default iptables rules?
Additionally:

Are there any risks or caveats to disabling Docker’s iptables modifications in favor of custom rules?
Is my current setup sufficient to ensure security and proper networking for Docker containers? If it is not then why?


Disable iptables in your daemon.json.
https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/dockerd/
Example /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "iptables": false
}


Is my current setup sufficient to ensure security and proper networking for Docker containers?

Probably not sufficient. There is almost certainly more rules you need to add related to port forwards. It gets more complicated as you have more docker networks. What requires depends on the specifics of your network and containers though.

I understand but what if I use only the default docker bridge network? Then will it be sufficient?

Unlikely.  You really should try spending some time on a testing system exporting (iptables-save) your rules with docker off, with docker on, and no containers, and after starting a container or two.  Then take time to understand the rules being added when docker starts, and when individual containers starts.
